# Does underneath imply a greater level of depth than beneath or below?

Tags: word-choice, meaning

I was trying to find the origin for the word "beneath" to see when it should be used instead of "below" and I [found](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nether) that it originated from be - neothan and was directed to see the definition of "nether":

> –adjective
>
> 1. lying or believed to lie beneath the earth's surface; infernal: the
>    nether regions.
> 2. lower or under: his nether lip.

I concluded that to be beneath, is to be below.

With this in mind, does that mean that the word underneath implies a greater level of depth than either beneath or below as it would literally mean "under low" instead of simply "being low"?

Comment: Note that "nether regions" nowadays is also used to refer to the buttocks and associated body parts. That being said, I would say that "beneath" and "underneath" are for the most part interchangeable.

Comment: People say "far beneath" rather than "far underneath" [(obligatory Ngram)](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=far+beneath%2C+deep+beneath%2C+far+underneath%2C+deep+underneath&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). I would say that this indicates that "beneath" is used for greater levels of depth.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, "underneath" does not imply a greater level of depth than either "beneath" or "below".

#### underneath

The *under-* indicates the subject of comparison is directly below the object or right "under its shadow". It also implies a total or partial concealment.

#### beneath

While the etymology of this word is slightly different (*bi/by-neothan/low*), it can be used interchangeably with "underneath", as @J. M. rightly pointed out in his comment on the question. However, the prefix *be* indicates another shade of meaning---"below the level of". Thus, if something or someone is below another, then it is not necessarily directly under but could also be at a lower level.

#### Examples

- ```
  The White River flows through the plains beneath the majestic slopes of Mount Verde.
  ```

  In this example, "beneath" cannot be interchanged with "underneath", as the plains cannot be physically *under* the mountain!
- ```
  Check that sorry pile of newspapers. I'm sure my watch is underneath.
  ```

  While it would not be incorrect to use "beneath" in place of "underneath" in this case, doing so would not be too stylistically pleasing for obvious reasons.
- ```
  I'm sure my watch is underneath that sorry pile of newspapers.
  ```

  Here, "beneath" can be substituted for "underneath" without inhibition!
- ```
  Beneath that great city lies an unparalleled tunnel network.
  ```

  "Underneath" can be used in place of "beneath" here, although "beneath" flows better, probably because of the word "lies".