# Does "neath" have any standalone meaning?

Tags: etymology, morphology

*Beneath* and *underneath* both indicate similar concepts, and since *under-* is a free morpheme in many contexts, is *neath* a bound morpheme or does it derive from a standalone root?

I bring this up since many instances of *underneath* and *beneath* can be replaced with *under.*

> "Where were your keys?"
>
> "They were under the couch." / "They were underneath the couch." /
>   "They were beneath the couch".

Comment: Regardless of any actual standalone root, *neath* sounds very Shakespearean. "She-ith sat-ith neath thee throne-ith." But I'm no Shakespearean scholar.

Comment: It's archaic. See my answer.

Comment: @NickAnderegg. What on Earth are those *-ith* suffixes supposed to mean? I can't make any sense of them at all.

Comment: It was mimicking thing -th in Middle English. It's like-o how-o you speak-o el Spanish-o by adding -o to everything. I'm no Shakespearean scholar. (To sum it up, it's a cheesy joke.)

Comment: Please consult a dictionary before asking meaning questions. If the [meaning as explained in a dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/neath?q=neath) is insufficient please expand on that in your question.

Comment: Also see might-be-a-duplicate [question #6785](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6785/does-underneath-imply-a-greater-level-of-depth-than-beneath-or-below), which question references origin of beneath.  Also see [question #56331](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56331/difference-between-underneath-and-under-when-we-describe-an-action?rq=1), with an answer that asserts «"underneath" is a concrete place, whereas "under" is a position».

Comment: Neath is a town in Wales http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neath

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Neath** or **'neath** does have a standalone meaning, but as you will see [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neath), it simply means beneath. It appears in poetry usually, I suspect, when beneath or underneath would add too many syllables to the line.

You can see its use in Google Ngrams [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beneath,underneath,neath&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) compared to beneath (most common) and underneath. It is quite rare, and declining:

[image]

Neath comes beneath underneath, which come underneath beneath!

Comment: Be careful; that probably includes the Welsh town, 'Neath'. And that pun is _beneath_ your standards. ;)

Comment: @rsegal isn't Ngrams case-sensitive? I believe it is.

Comment: [Google says](http://books.google.com/ngrams/info), "the Ngram Viewer is case-sensitive".

Comment: Yes: Google N-Grams is case-***sensitive***, but Google Books searches are case-***insensitive***.  Both do odd, and unequal, things with punctuation.

Comment: Ngrams is [kinda weird about punctuation and case](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=FRENCH+TOAST%2Cfrench+toast%2C+French+toast&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). (That graph would make it seem like Ngrams pays attention to case, but, if you look through the actual results, it's not quite so straightforward as you might think just by looking at the graph alone).

Comment: Unless you can show it being used from the ME period on, that doen't discount those of us saying that *neath* comes from *beneath* rather than the other way around.

Comment: @JAM I have no idea. I flagged it _in case_ it was an issue. As long as people are aware of the issues, the right thing usually gets done.

Comment: It seems that neath from Proto-Indo-European *ni- (“down”).

Answer (score 7):

In Old English, you could create a verb from another word by prefixing it with *be-*, as in *become*, *besiege*, *bedaub*, *befriend*.

*beneothan* meant "make far-down", while the related *neothera* meant "more far down".

Their shared root, *neothan*, that had it survived we could expect to have become *neath* and to mean "far-down", dropped out of the language, and meanwhile *beneath* became the preposition it now is, while *nether* became close to what that shared root once meant.

Meanwhile *underneothan* (under the low-down thing) became *underneath*.

*'neath* as a contraction comes from *beneath*, rather than *beneath* coming from *neath* as you may expect, though they all share a common Old English root.

Comment: I don't think the *be-* prefix with *neath* has much connection with *besiege, besmirch, befriend,* etc. It's more related to *by*, in that it identifies ***location***, rather than action/transformation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *befriend* etc. also come from *be-* that is from *by-*.

Comment: Etymologically speaking I've no reason to disagree with that. I'm just saying that the *current significance* of the prefix as used in *behind, below, beneath, beyond*, etc. isn't the same as the current significance of that same prefix in words like *besiege, besmirch, befriend*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question is tagged with "etymology", so that's what I addressed. Now, the two meanings of *be-* are more distinct, as you say.

Comment: True enough - I must admit I wasn't really thinking about that aspect. It's not that I thought your first sentence was *wrong* - I just didn't think it was overly relevant to *beneath*. Anyway, I certainly agree your last sentence, which exactly addresses the crucial point that modern *neath* isn't a hangover from OE. It's a (now dated/poetic) contraction of the (relatively) modern *beneath*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I find it sort of fun how there was a word that had be- prefixed to it to make beneath, and then it ended up being split off again. The best example of that is when "Wicca" was taken from OE, almost certainly quite deliberately, and then modern English adjective rules produced "Wiccan" which happened to be the same spelling (different pronouciation) as the OE plural. I like these little coincidences.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It is an aphetic variant of the preposition *beneath* It was first used in 1787. As in:

> - He then placed jack stands under *neath* the rear suspension.

> - *Neath* his calm surface, there was seething anger

It is now considered archaic and/or poetic. It is often spelled *'neath*. It is frequently preceded by the word *under*.

Comment: I thought the *'neath* form was a poetic form of *beneath.* Just the same word with the prefix cut off. Like how *never do well* turns in to *n'er do well.*

Answer (score 1):

It seems that 'neath' is a development of 'nether', and has similar (though archaic) meaning.

Answer (score -1):

The two words have no connection for "neath" has at its heart location while "neither" is comparative and has no location connotation save one of the compared items might be considered of lesser (or lower)value.

Comment: The question was about "neath" as extracted from "beneath"/"underneath"; "Neither" was never involved in it, so I don't understand your answer.