# Difference between "under", "underneath", "below" and "beneath"

Tags: differences, prepositions, orthography

It leads me to the confusion, when it comes to contradicting between some prepositions.

Today, I want to know the distinction between the two similar senses of these prepositions: [under](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/under), [underneath](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/underneath), [below](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/below) and [beneath](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/beneath).

**Sense No. 1.** extending **directly** below (something else) or extending **directly** underneath.

The following example sentence suggests that we can use all of the four prepositions mentioned above:

> 1. Our bedroom is right **under** theirs.
>
>    2. Our bedroom is right **underneath** theirs.
>
> I am not sure wether this sentence 2 can this be like this: **underneath** theirs, is our bedroom.
>
> 3. Our bedroom is right **below** theirs.
> 4. Our bedroom is right **beneath** theirs.

---

**Sense No. 2.** at a lower level or layer than, or so as to be concealed.

The sentence for this sense:

> 1. The tunnel **under** the crags . . .
> 2. The tunnel **underneath** the crags . . .
> 3. The tunnel **below** the crags . . .
> 4. The tunnel **beneath** the crags . . .

**The Oxford Dictionaries site provides the same definitions of these two senses of under, underneath, below, beneath.** In terms of these two senses, is there any subtle difference between these four prepositions? Or one is most formal/informal than the rest.

---

And what about their spelling pattern:

> If under is to under**neath**, but why below is to be**neath**, rather than below**neath**?

Comment: [A thread on Myenglishteacher.eu has addressed this exact issue in great detail](https://www.myenglishteacher.eu/ask/question/difference-between-beneath-under-underneath-and-below/). Question will therefore be flagged for closure.

Comment: @VTH, the link you provided does not answer my question in some, nor that is as same as my question is. In the link, the website says in its first point: "under is used when something
is **directly** under another." but here I want to ask that the OED provides the same definitions of all these prepositions, denoting that they are **directly** below or under something else.

Comment: You stated, and I quote: "Is there any subtle difference between these prepositions? Or one is most formal/informal than the rest." Nothing about "(why) OED provides the same definitions of all these prepositions" was ever mentioned in the question. If you want to ask why the four definitions are so similar on OED, then please make an edit to reflect that fact.

Comment: @VTH, Okay, well, going to do that. :)

Comment: It's not the OED, it's Oxford Dictionaries. The first (extremely exhaustive and detailed) is available only on subscription, the second,  its sister-site, is free and available to everyone.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What is the name of the "sister-site"?

Comment: Use *beneath* and *underneath* in set phrases and idiomatic expressions. For all practical purposes, these are deprecated.

Comment: @Kris Oxford Dictionaries -- check out the links added to the question. Same publisher, different work though.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6785/does-underneath-imply-a-greater-level-of-depth-than-beneath-or-below

Comment: I answered a similar question here [What is the difference between 'entry' and 'entrance', and 'admission' and 'admittance'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/419739/what-is-the-difference-between-entry-and-entrance-and-admission-and-admi) Reading it may probably help you.

Comment: @VTH Do we close as duplicates questions that are asked on other sites?

Comment: @AzorAhai If you flag the post using the **a duplicate...** option, then no, since you need to link to another question that also exists on English Stack Exchange (that you suspect this post is a duplicate of) for your closure request to be accepted.

Comment: @VTH Then what vote reason did you think people would use?

Comment: @AzorAhai "in need of moderator intervention" perhaps? Regardless, it doesn't matter much since my initial flag for this question was declined.

Comment: @VTH But that's not a close reason? I was just unsure why you thought htis question should be closed.

Comment: Related post https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/111714/underneath-beneath-for-hidden-things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are four very similar words, and while native English speakers will likely agree on which one to choose in a given context, they would probably find it difficult to say why. The differences are extremely subtle, and there's a degree of overlap.

Rather than presenting standard dictionary definitions, I found that an etymological analysis helped me get a better sense of the usage:

[**below (adv.)**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/below)

> "in a lower position," early 14c., *biloogh*, from *be-* "by, about" + *logh, lou, lowe* "low" [...] Apparently a variant of earlier *a-lowe* (influenced by other adverbs in *be-*; see **before**), the parallel form to *an-high* (now *on high*).
>
> *Beneath* was the usual word; *below* was very rare in Middle English and gained currency only in 16c. It is frequent in Shakespeare. As a preposition from 1570s. In nautical use, "off-duty," in contradistinction to "on deck." Meaning "inferior in rank or dignity" is from c. 1600.
>
> According to Fowler, *below* is the opposite of *above* and concerns difference of level and suggests comparison of independent things. *Under* is the opposite of *over* and is concerned with superposition and subjection and suggests some interrelation.

[**beneath (adv., prep.)**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/Beneath)

> Old English *beneoðan* "under, below, in a lower place, further down than," in late Old English "lower in rank, degree, excellence, etc.," from *be-* "by" + *neoðan* "below, down, from below," from Proto-Germanic **niþar* "lower, farther down, down" (see nether). Meaning "unworthy of" is attested from 1849 (purists prefer *below* in this sense). "The *be-* gave or emphasized the notion of 'where,' excluding that of 'whence' pertaining to the simple *niðan*" [OED].

[**under (prep., adv.)**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/under)

> Old English under (prep.) "beneath, among, before, in the presence of, in subjection to, under the rule of, by means of," also, as an adverb, "beneath, below, underneath," expressing position with reference to that which is above, from Proto-Germanic *under- (source also of Old Frisian under, Dutch onder, Old High German untar, German unter, Old Norse undir, Gothic undar), from PIE *ndher- "under" (source also of Sanskrit adhah "below;" Avestan athara- "lower;" Latin infernus "lower," infra "below").
>
> Productive as a prefix in Old English, as in German and Scandinavian (often forming words modeled on Latin ones in sub-). Notion of "inferior in rank, position, etc." was present in Old English. With reference to standards, "less than in age, price, value," etc., late 14c. As an adjective, "lower in position; lower in rank or degree" from 13c. Also

[**underneath (adv.)**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/underneath)

> Old English *underneoðan*, from **under** + *neoðan* "below" (see **beneath**).

This duplication of meanings serves to emphasise an immediacy or directness in the locational relationship. [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/underneath) says "Situated directly below (something else)".

---

So, to very broadly summarise:

- **below** is more likely to indicate a simple *level* in an above/below duality
- **beneath** adds a hint of *inferiority* or lower *order*
- **under** tends to be used in a *superposition* of related/connected things
- **underneath** is like "under" but more immediately or directly so.

---

Regarding your question about "spelling patterns", this is partly explained above in the etymology. To elaborate on "below" and "beneath": they're each composed of the prefix "be-" (a directional indicator) plus a locational word - "low", or "neath" (related to "nether" - think of the Netherlands = "low country").

**[be-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/be-)**

> word-forming element of verbs and nouns from verbs, with a wide range of meaning: "about, around; thoroughly, completely; to make, cause seem; to provide with; at, on, to, for;" from Old English *be-* "about, around, on all sides" (the unstressed form of *bi* "by").

---

Finally, to demonstrate how subtle and indeed fickle the differences are:

- **that behaviour was *beneath* him** - but we probably wouldn't use "below" and definitely not "under" or "underneath";
- **that performance was *below* par** - or maybe "under par" but definitely not "beneath" or "underneath";
- **she slid the key *underneath* the mat** - "under" would work just as well, but "beneath" would be a bit unusual and we wouldn't use "below";
- **I'm *below* the age limit** - "under" is probably just as common but seems a bit more colloquial, while neither "beneath" nor "underneath" would be used.

Comment: I've accepted your detailed, well-defined answer, but can you please add some information about the **spelling pattern** of these four prepositions. I've asked this in my question, too.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. I've added a spelling explanation for the two "be-" words; the other two words are already explained in the etymology section. Hope that completes what you're after :-)

Comment: Some of your statements are incorrect: "beneath adds a hint of inferiority or lower order", That is not true for physical things. You do not make the physical/non-physical distinction.

Comment: ***under tends to be used in a superposition of related/connected things*** that is not true. Under is not about "superposition", which is relevant or a word much used in English. Only people are fickle, never things.

Answer (score 2):

While **below** and **under** *can* be used in the same sentences as **beneath** and **underneath**, there is a subtle difference which may be more apparent depending on context.

**Under** and **below** denote proximity in two dimensions - in other words: If you were looking at a page with a picture of a table near the top and a picture of an apple closer to the bottom, you could say that the apple is ***under*** or ***below*** the table. It would be more likely to say that the apple is ***beneath***, or ***underneath***, the table if visual cues indicated that the apple occupied a space (in three dimensions) which the table stood over.

Answer (score 2):

Although the four words are frequently used interchangeably, somewhat different senses can be made or understood - i.e. the **"direct or immediate" position** of something as opposed to a more **"general" position** of something (meaning simply lower than). The prepositions under and below would more commonly be used in a general sense.

> - The ball is on the floor [below](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/below) the table (anywhere on the floor below the table).
> - The ball is on the floor [beneath](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/beneath) the table (typically understood as **directly below** the table).
> - The ball is on the floor [under](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/under) the table (generally on the floor **under** the table).
> - The ball is on the floor [underneath](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/underneath) the table (positioned directly under the table).

---

Your final question is interesting. I would have to agree that the preposition 'underneath' does seem to be redundant. Just looking at its old English origin (see the [etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=underneath) for underneath) - possibly this was for emphasis.

Comment: Yes, the prepositional uses.

Answer (score 0):

**Underneath**, to me, connotes an aspect of being *hidden*.

"There were old grapes underneath the fridge" (= they were under the fridge but we could not see them/we did not know they were there [initially or at some point in time]); versus

"The linoleum under the fridge needs to be replaced" (= its position is lower than the fridge, but its existence is immediately known to the speaker).

"There were centipedes underneath the large rock we removed" (= the centipedes had been hidden; the speaker had not known they were under the rock until the rock was moved) versus

"The soil below rocks retains its moisture much longer than soil exposed to the sun." (= the speaker is already aware of the soil lower than the rocks; it's merely a statement of physical position).

So for me *underneath* connotes something usually physical, tangible, that is or was initially unknown or hidden versus *under* which is more neutral.

**Beneath** as discussed in earlier entries can for sure give the feeling of something or someone in an inferior position.  For example:

"Being seen in that type of establishment is beneath me" (= I consider that establishment not to be equal to my standards).

That more abstract, usually less physical quality, when intentionally used by the speaker/author to describe a physical situation, gives the word a bit more poetic, literary feeling.  Also, as with *underneath*, it can create a feeling of stealth, of intention, of figuratively hiding something as opposed to hiding an object; this feeling is not really connoted as much in *under* or *below*.

Consider reading in a story:  "The maid had worked for the family for years, obliterating dust from every corner of their mansion.  Being tidy, she kept her overcoat on a hook next to the kitchen door and her broom and dustpan in a closet under the back stairs."  (= simple position; you could also say beneath the back stairs for alliteration, but it's a closet with a broom, nothing special).

Versus:  "The maid knew where the family's skeletons were buried, but, in truth, how well did they know *her*?  She maintained a tidy home and proper demeanor at all times.  Little did the family know that she hid her own secrets in the closet beneath the staircase."  Here *beneath* gives a more literary tone; it suggests something potentially physical -- like a note or diary -- but also possibly figurative, non-literal, like secret knowledge, blackmail, or maybe she quietly sobs in that closet during moments of emotional breakdown, and no one's the wiser; etc. -- it plays with the liminality between the physical and the ethereal much better than *under* does.  Also, *beneath* in the latter context takes on some of the connotation of *underneath*, namely something hidden:  hidden knowledge, hidden resentment, hidden emotions, hidden motives; however, with only two syllables, *beneath* feels cleaner and more figurative than the clunkier, tri-syllabic *underneath*, which feels much more descriptive of something physically hidden.

I would say, for example, "he hid the weapon underneath his bed," but "she hid her exasperation beneath a fake smile".

**Below** to me -- yes, in the *above/below* binary -- is also a bit stationary.

"You can find the vinegar below the sugar in aisle 3." And:

"Books on the American Revolution sit on the shelf above books on the U.S. Civil War."

Also with *above-below*, there seems to be an *understood or implied relationship*.  "One shelf is above another.  One shelf is below the other."

*Under* and *underneath* both feel awkward in this example. *Beneath* feels like too much -- like someone trying to sound fancier than they need to; I would give small side-eye to hearing "One shelf is beneath another" -- it gives a "no duh" feeling -- like they're trying to say something intelligent that is obvious, whereas above/below does not give me that feeling, it would merely be the speaker indicating where one thing is in relationship to another (e.g., where an object is), on which shelf, plain and simple. Clear and clean.

**Under** -- in the **over/under** duality -- *under* is imbued with a strong sense of *motion or movement* that words like *below* generally lack and *beneath* may or may not lack depending on the context.

Consider:

"One box is *below* another," but "The child crawled *under* the table."

Most native speakers would not say "The child crawled below the table."  It just sounds weird.  More examples:

"The child's ball rolled *under* the couch," and
"The rat ran *under* the porch."  (Most would not say "The rat ran below the porch"). You could also say "The rat ran underneath the porch," really emphasizing the feeling in the listener's or reader's mind that the rat is now hiding under the porch.  In this instance you could also say "The rat ran beneath the porch." !!!  Why? Because beneath can connote below in a more stationary way (1) in a situation where there's not an already-implied or -understood expected relationship between the objects and/or (2) where pairing the stationary *below* with a verb of movement ("ran") just feels awkward.  *Beneath* works because of its overlapping meaning of below (lower than) and under (movement while lower than) it can be used with movement.

So movement/motion is at play with *over* and *under*.  In the *above* versus *over* distinction, now we're talking about something we consider to be stationary (at least at that moment) in relative position to something else:

"A flag flew *above* the castle" (= more stationary) versus
"A ball flew *over* the fence" (was above and crossed the fence in a trajectory).

Over/under denote motion, movement, trajectory; above/below denote a more stationary position of one thing relative to another.  Here's another example:

"It was such a loud morning! The police helicopter hovered *above* our neighbor's house while a jet flew *over* our neighborhood. We didn't have a moment's peace!"  *Above* gives that feeling of stationary relative position versus *over* describing something in motion.

These are my thoughts at least.  I will say while I'm no linguist, I do spend a lot of time translating text between English and French, and the two languages' prepositions -- how they work, how they pair with verbs, the denotations versus connotions they give -- at times could not seem more different.  It can be very difficult to translate something seemingly so obvious in one language into the other and have it feel natural.

Overall, I'd say that in English we have what one might call "stronger" prepositions -- as parts of speech they have lots of independence in terms of pairing them up with different verbs in ways that convey a lot of meaning, whereas French has "weaker" prepositions that can be paired only with certain verbs and which generally carry much less of the meaning of the sentence than their verbs do.  In the above examples, the sense of motion and movement versus stationary or the slight connotation of whether the speaker knows of something or if something is initially hidden or unknown carried by the prepositions does not translate easily into French, where the verbs themselves rather than prepositions would hold such meaning.

Anyway, thems my thoughts.  Not sure if it helps anyone, but I thought I'd share since I'm a language lover and nerd.  Here are my final examples, and please feel free to disagree with me!!!

1. A river ran below the hillside town.
2. A river ran beneath the hillside town.
3. A river ran under the hillside town.
4. A river ran underneath the hillside town.

In these examples, the image I as the writer have in my head are as follows:

1. The position of the two things is stationary: the river is topographically lower relative to the higher town.   Their relative positions are not changing.  It reads like background description, nothing more. End of story.
2. Same as above; although a slight question arises in my mind: Is the river simply lower than the town that's on the hill side? Or is the river flowing under the ground directly below/beneath the town?  Beneath, to me, is a more ambiguous choice. In some contexts, it could leave a question in the reader's or listener's mind.
3. There is an underground river in the earth on which the town was built and is sitting.  And it's a progressive feeling:  the river was still in the process of running under this town.  The sense of motion in under gives it a progressive, as-yet-unfinished, still-occurring feeling in some contexts.  Nothing in this sentence suggests that the townspeople didn't know there was a river beneath their feet.  Under reads as neutral movement.
4. Same as #3, but gives me a connotation of hidden/unknown.  Perhaps the townspeople didn't realize there was an underground river beneath their feet.  To me I could also imagine a sense of recency with underneath.  As in, a river had just started to flow underneath the hillside town, as in an ancient underground riverbed had somehow come back to life, and perhaps that's why no one knew yet.  That's just the feeling I get with underneath.

Answer (score -4):

There are uses of these words for physical things, and non-physical things. There's the rub.

1) Our bedroom is right "under, below, underneath or beneath theirs". All four mean the same thing. And everything here is physical.

There is no real difference. Just as if you tell your carpenter, "I want to build a walk-in closet in my bedroom which is under the attic". the meaning would not change if you use any of those terms.

However, there is this: as an adverb, beneath is used like this:

> "What lies beneath is a large cavern."  There, "beneath" is an adverb
>   and tells us where the cavern lies. Here, only beneath, underneath,and
>   below can be used. You cannot use "what lies under" here, only "what
>   lies underneath". So, beneath and underneath can be adverbs.
>
> Under cannot be used as an adverb in the sense of the cavern sentence. It is a preposition.
>   And can also be used in the phrasal verb,for example: go under. The business went under
>   last week. meaning: stopped running due to monetary issues. go under
>   is like "drown". And can literally mean to drown, also.
>
> That said, in some contexts, below and under (beneath,underneath) are
>   not 100%.
>
> "My house lay below theirs on a beautiful, flower-covered
>   hillside". In a vertical-type plane, below means located at a lower
>   level on that same plane. Here, we would not say "under". In this
>   sense, none of the others work. And this is the tricky one, too.

There is also the use of beneath referring to a more moral sense: I would not do that,it is beneath me aka below me. On a moral plane,some action or behavior is considered to "beneath one"and colloquially, "below one".

Finally, in a textual context, we say: The explanation is in the paragraph below. (not: below paragraph!)  A portion of text can be below or above some other text.

A graphic image can be under(or beneath or underneath) another one though. That is location in space just like the attic above. Beneath and underneath are not preferred here. A painting can be hung on a wall in the same way: under,beneath,underneath or below another painting.

I think I explained this pretty thoroughly. Someone may come up with some detail I missed. Everything is possible.